# Latexmk - Non-existent destination files

Tags: texmaker, latexmk

I try to use latexmk with Texmaker.

I put that in the Quick build :

> "C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/latexmk" -pdf %.tex |
>   "C:/Program Files/Adobe/Reader 11.0/Acrobat/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf

I had this answer :

> Process started
>
> Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 5 February 2015, version:
>   4.43a.
>
> Rule 'cusdep glo gls main': File changes, etc:
>
> Non-existent destination files: 'main.gls' ------------ Run number 1
>   of rule 'cusdep glo gls main' ------------
>
> Index style file 'main'.gst not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT]
>   [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
>
> Rule 'cusdep glo gls main', function 'makeglo2gls' failed with return
>   code = 256
>
> Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
>
> cusdep glo gls main: Command for 'cusdep glo gls main' gave return
>   code 256 Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
>   unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
>
> Process exited with error(s)

I used was it written [there](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/YgVkjDN73w8) (I have only changed 'makeglossaries' by 'makeglossary' in the code written) now I have this message :

> Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 5 February 2015, version:
>   4.43a.
>
> Rule 'makeindex auteurs.idx': File changes, etc:
>
> Non-existent destination files: 'auteurs.ind' ------------ Run number
>   1 of rule 'makeindex auteurs.idx' ------------
>
> ------------ Running 'makeindex "auteurs.idx";splitindex "auteurs.idx";' ------------
>
> Input index file auteurs.idx;splitindex not found. Usage: makeindex
>   [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
>
> Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
>
> makeindex auteurs.idx: Command for 'makeindex auteurs.idx' gave return
>   code 256 Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
>   unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
>
> Process exited with error(s)

Knowing that "auteurs" means "author" in French.

I do not find what is the following step...

Comment: I copied my file auteurs.idx and created with that a auteurs.ind, now it goes until "------------ Running 'xelatex -recorder "main.tex"' ----------" and never continues...

Comment: In both cases, it would help to know exactly how latexmk is configured, i.e., what is the exact definition of the custom dependency/dependencies that you used, as well as other definitions.  In the second case, my first conjecture is that you have redefined $makeindex in a way that works for UNIX-like systems but is wrong for MS-Windows.  (The semicolon separates commands on UNIX, but is taken as part of a filename in MS-Windows.)